# add separate values to DropDownButton

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a widget with a item builder. In the item builder I want to create Drop down for each item.

For the `value` property of this `DropdownMenuItem` i use 
`SaleRef _selectedRef;`

The problem is when I declare this `SaleRef _selectedRef;` inside the **itemBuilder** the value does not change after selecting a item.

When I declare it outside this widget but in the class it changes the value of every dropdown

> What can I do to select separate values on every drop down ?

**This is the code for creating the items**

```
ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Row(
                    children: <Widget>[                      
                      Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1 / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              width: 0.80),
                        ),
                        child: DropdownButton<SaleRef>(
                          hint: Text("  Select Ref"),
                          value: _selectedRef,
                          onChanged: (SaleRef value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedRef = value;
                              print(_selectedRef.refID);
                            });
                          },
                          items: _filteredSaleRef.map((SaleRef ref) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<SaleRef>(
                              value: ref,
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    "  " + ref.refName,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Divider(height: 16);
                },
                itemCount: filteredShopItem.length,
              )
```

**When I declare it like this**

```
class _AssignRefPageState extends State<AssignRefPage>
    with  {

  SaleRef _selectedRef;
```

**This happens after selecting a value**

[image]

**When I declare it like this inside the builder like this**

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   SaleRef _selectedRef;
                  return Row(
```

This is what I get it's always the hint even after I select a one

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Josteve-Adekanbi said the problem was using the same variable

Creating an array with a size outside the class helped me solve my problem

```
List<SaleRef> _selectedRef = new List(filteredShopItem.length);
```

Then I used it like this

```
                         DropdownButton<SaleRef>(
                          hint: Text("  Select Ref"),
                          value: _selectedRef[index],
                          onChanged: (SaleRef value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedRef[index] = value;
                              print(_selectedRef[index].refID);
                            });
                          }
```

Comment: @sathura hey, how can i do the same above to, two dependable drop downs in a List.View Builder ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the same variable for every dropdownbutton and when you try to declare it in the ListView `itemBuilder` and you call setState the whole Widget is built setting it to null again

What you can do is create a List of values(the size should be number of dropdownbuttons you have)

Like this

```
class _AssignRefPageState extends State<AssignRefPage>
    with  {

  List<SaleRef>_selectedRef = List.generate(numberOfDropDowns, (index) => SaleRef());
```

Then use the array in your setState

```
DropdownButton<SaleRef>(
                          hint: Text("  Select Ref"),
                          value: _selectedRef,
                          onChanged: (SaleRef value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedRef[index] = value;
                              print(_selectedRef[index].refID); //<- The index is from itemBuilder
                            });
                          }
```

Comment: it throws this error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`